# Axios + Vue + ag-grid-vue ... Dependency not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, npm-install, ag-grid-vue

So, I'm pretty new to VueJS. Integrating axios has never really been a problem on any of my other apps, but for some reasons this one just won't show up.

It doesn't like npm only, or CDN only, or the current implementation of CDN+npm install.

Hope y'all can help me out! Not really sure what the issue is, and googling hasn't been too helpful.

~Desired Outcome:
post via axios within vue application

~Current Status Error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error 
"This dependency was not found:

* https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js?vue&type=script&lang=js& in ./src/App.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&"
```

~What Happened when Running Above Command in zShell:
`` zsh: parse error near `&' ``

~package.json file:

```
  "name": "ag-grid",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "start": "App.vue"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.2.1",
    "ag-grid-vue": "^25.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

~Relevant script code:

```
    import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";
    import { axios } from "axios";
    import { VueAxios } from "vue-axios";
```

Comment: One obvious issue is that you should be importing the default export from the `axios` package.  So it should be `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: How is your code translating the `axios` import to the URL indicated in the error message? Are you using a Webpack alias to pull in `axios` from `unpkg.com`? That would not work.

Comment: thanks friends. i had to define axios like this:
```
const axios = require('axios')
```
within the function that was using it.